# Open Sets of Convergence Space Induce a Topology (and vice versa)

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, filters

It's Christmas holidays and I have some time to read about filter convergence. But I am not sure about the following exercise:

Let $X$ be a space equipped with a convergence (i.e. a relation $\xi\subseteq X\times\mathfrak F$ satisfying some conditions, c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_space#Definition_of_(pre)convergence_spaces ; here $\mathfrak F$ denotes the set of filters over $X$), and let $\mathcal T$ be a set of subsets of $X$.

I want to show that

> $\mathcal T$ is a topology over $X$ if and only if $\mathcal T = \big\{O\subseteq X : \text{for each $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$ it holds that $O\in\mathcal F$ whenever $\lim\mathcal F\cap O\neq\emptyset$}\big\}$.

I think I figured out the "$\Leftarrow$"-direction:

> Let $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$ be such that $\lim\mathcal F\cap\emptyset \neq \emptyset$. Thus, it's vacuously true that $\emptyset\in\mathcal T$. Let $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$ such that $\lim\mathcal F\cap X\neq\emptyset$. It follows from the definition of a filter that $X\in\mathcal F$. Thus, $X\in\mathcal T$.
>
> Let $A,B\in\mathcal T$, and let $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$ such that $\lim\mathcal F\cap (A\cap B)\neq\emptyset$. Since $A\cap B\subseteq A$ it follows that $\lim\mathcal F\cap A\neq\emptyset$. By hypothesis, $A\in\mathcal T$. Hence it follows from the definition of $\mathcal T$ that $A\in\mathcal F$. Similarly, since $A\cap B\subseteq B$ it follows that $\lim\mathcal F\cap B\neq\emptyset$. By hypothesis, $B\in\mathcal T$. Hence it follows from the definition of $\mathcal T$ that $B\in\mathcal F$. Consequently, $A\cap B\in\mathcal F$ by definition of a filter. Thus, $A\cap B\in\mathcal T$.
>
> Let $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal T$. Let $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$ such that $\lim\mathcal F\cap \left(\bigcup\mathcal A\right)\neq\emptyset$. So there exists some $A\in\mathcal A$ such that $\lim\mathcal F\cap A\neq\emptyset$. By assumption, $A\in\mathcal T$. Hence it follows from the definition of $\mathcal T$ that $A\in\mathcal F$. Since $A\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal A$, it follows from the definition of a filter that $\bigcup\mathcal A\in\mathcal F$. Thus, $\bigcup\mathcal A\in\mathcal T$.
>
> That is, $\mathcal T$ is a topology over $X$.

Is my proof fine? I followed the steps discussed in this question and added some details: [Topology of a convergence space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/704084/topology-of-a-convergence-space)

I have some problems with the "$\Rightarrow$"-direction:

> For each $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$, put $$\lim\mathcal F:=  \big\{x\in X : \text{for each $N\in\mathcal N(x)$ there exists some $F\in\mathcal F$ with $F\subseteq N$. }\big\},$$ where $\mathcal N(x)$ denotes the neighborhood filter of $x\in X$, i.e. $$\mathcal N(x) := \big\{N\subseteq X : \text{there exists some $U\in\mathcal T$ with $x\in U$ and $U\subseteq N$}\big\}.$$
>
> "$\subseteq$": Let $O\in\mathcal T$ and consider some $F\in\mathfrak F$ with $\lim\mathcal F\cap O\neq\emptyset$. Hence there is some $x\in O$ with $x\in\lim\mathcal F$. So for each $N\in\mathcal N(x)$ there is some $F\in\mathcal F$ such that $F\subseteq N$. In particular, there is some $F\in\mathcal F$ such that $F\subseteq O$, as $O\in\mathcal N(x)$ since $O\in\mathcal T$ by hypothesis as well as $x\in O$ and $O\subseteq O$. Thus, it follows from the definition of a filter that $O\in\mathcal F$.
>
> "$\supseteq$": Let $O\subseteq X$ and $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$ such that $O\in\mathcal F$ whenever $\lim\mathcal F\cap O\neq\emptyset$. Let $x\in O$ and consider $\mathcal N(x)$. Note that $\mathcal N(x)\in\mathfrak F$ and $x\in\lim\mathcal N(x)$, so  $\lim\mathcal N(x)\cap O\neq\emptyset$. Hence it follows from the hypothesis that $O\in\mathcal N(x)$. So there exists some $U_x\in\mathcal T$ such that $x\in U_x$ and $U_x\subseteq O$. Define $\mathcal A :=\{ U_x : x\in O\}$. Clearly, $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal T$, so $\bigcup\mathcal A\in\mathcal T$ by definition of a topology. Since $$O = \bigcup_{x\in O}\{x\} \subseteq \bigcup_{x\in O}U_x \subseteq O$$ it follows that $\bigcup\mathcal A = O$. Hence $O\in\mathcal T$.
>
> That is, $\mathcal T = \big\{O\subseteq X : \text{for each $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$ it holds that $O\in\mathcal F$ whenever $\lim\mathcal F\cap O\neq\emptyset$}\big\}$.

I am not sure about this direction. Especially in the second part, I only showed it for a particular choice of $\mathcal F\in\mathfrak F$ (namely $\mathcal N(x)$). But I don't know how to prove it for a general choice of $\mathcal F$... To be honest, I am not even sure whether the proof of the "$\Rightarrow$"-direction is correct at all.

Are the other steps ok, though? Is there anything else that needs to be corrected?

**Edit 1:** Thinking again about this, the "$\Rightarrow$"-direction cannot be true. If it was true, then there would be a topology for each type of filter convergence. However, there are types of filter convergence (i.e. almost sure convergence) that cannot be described by a topology. So the right side needs to be modified. But how?

**Edit 2:** The exercise may has to be modified too in order to overcome the issue mentioned in Edit 1.